# Reset results if filter input is empty

Tags: php, jquery

I created a simple search as you type that replaces a DIV (which is originally populated by PHP). The function works fine. But I cannot get it to reset to original state if the input field is blank.

Here is the script:

```
$("#search_user").keyup(function()
  {
  var search_user = $(this).val();
  var dataString = 'keyword='+ search_user;
  if(search_user.length>3)
  {
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "../functions/search.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(server_response)
        {
          $('#list_users').html(server_response);
        }
  });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Original DIV code:

```
    <div id="list_users">
   <?php echo "
          <div class=\"col-md-3\">
            <img src=\"../assets/img/avatars/1.jpg\" class=\"user-avatar\">
            <div class=\"caption\">
              <h5>$rows[user_full_name] <br> <small> Designer</small></h5>
            </div>
          </div> 
      " ;?>
           </div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does it look like in original state?

Comment: @ShaunakD Added the original state code - Its an echo from PHP function. the filtered results are the same but shows only the one matches the search keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
var $copy = $("#list_users").html();
$("#search_user").keyup(function() {
  var search_user = $(this).val();
  if(search_user=="") $("#list_users").html($copy);
  else {
```

Comment: I don't think that would work. since the $list_users is the DIV that contains the original code that is being replaced by the script.

Comment: In your code it is the container that is filled by the success of the ajax

Comment: Correct. I am added the div and wrapped it around the original code so I can replace it.

Comment: If you want to keep the div, take a copy and replace my empty() with html($copy)

Comment: you have an extra $ in $copy

Comment: I use $copy to show that the var contains a jQuery object and not just a string

Answer (score 2):

You can save the state of original html (On DOM ready, before you carry out any operations on it).

```
var originalState = $("#list_users").html();

$("#search_user").keyup(function() {
  var search_user = $(this).val();
  if(search_user=="") $("#list_users").html(originalState );
```

Comment: Hey. So did mine. I am just slower to type on my phone where as he just had to copy my code for the first example and read your comment on my answer

Comment: Hmm I guess I just have to _Let it go, let it goooo_

Comment: @mplungjan, *Let it go, let it goooo*, Linkin Park track? :D  EDarrien, please accept his answer. He was first, though on the phone. And I did not copy your answer nor read your comment. I was confirming my answer in a fiddle. You can see this [Comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29861078/reset-results-if-filter-input-is-empty/29861154#comment47847994_29861078), I was the first one to ask him for the original state as had this solution in mind wayyyy before you typed it on your phone.

Comment: I was pretty sure you copied my code (not that you needed to but still) since the spacing was identical. That  is why...

Comment: @ShaunakD changed the answer post. Both answers were correct . appreciate it.